# Installed certificates on Batch account and Pool not available for task

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have an Azure Batch account setup with system assigned identity (*the account was created through TF and User assigned identities are not yet supported*).

A certificate is available to the batch account and on the pool as well.

[image: batch account certificate image]

[image: pool certificate image]

When inspecting the node on the pool (scaled to one for now), it shows a certificate reference:

[image: Node certificate reference]

I've manually created a job and a simple task (`/bin/bash -c 'ls -la $AZ_BATCH_CERTIFICATES_DIR/'`) to list contents and everything comes empty.

This seems to be the case for all self-signed certificates I've used to try this.

Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong?
(I've tried all combinations for `Task-NonAdmin, TaskAdmin, Pool-NonAdmin, Pool-Admin together with LocalMachine, currentUser`).

Thanks all!

Comment: @Venkataraman R - Thanks for the edit. Given my profile, I could not display images.

Comment: Did you add the certificate after the pool was created? If so, you have to reboot existing nodes for the new certificates to be picked up.

Comment: @fpark Yes. I did all sorts of combinations. In fact, the certs reference on the node is there as you can see on the last picture. But the certs are not made available to the tasks.

Comment: @AnibalKolker any update on this. I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Jase_ Unfortunately not. I ended up pulling certificates and whatnot from a key vault using managed identities.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this thing happened:

Issue with Windows LocalMachine certificates:

If you are adding certificate references on your pool which install into the Windows LocalMachine certificate store, and are running tasks without admin access which need access to the certificate's private key, your tasks will work on the old agent but not work in the new agent.

Only pfx files where your non-admin task needs access to the private key should be moved to "My" in CurrentUser

https://github.com/Azure/Batch/issues/1

If I upload the certs to CurrentUser\My, the tasks do get the certs.